# Accessibility not working properly on changing height constraint for a textview in ios

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm adding accessibility support for my app and there is a scenario where I'm changing the height constraint of a TextView to 0 and 44.
I'm disabling the accessibility when the height is 0 and vice versa. But on doing so, when the height becomes 44, and even though the accessibility is ON for the `UITextView`; the accessibility cursor is never pointing the `UITextView` unless until I switch off & on the Accessibility.

Disabling/enabling the accessibility, hiding the accessibility elements

```
textView.accessibilityElementsHidden = true

textView.disableAccessibility()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and implemented your use case in a blank project as follows:
[image]

`Button H 0` leads to a zero textview height and disables the textview accessibility while `Button H 44` leads to a 44 textview height and enables the textview accessibility.

The corresponding code *(Swift 5.0, iOS 12)* is defined hereunder:

```
class SOFViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // Action for "BUTTON H O"
    @IBAction func heightIsZero(_ sender: UIButton) {
        heightConstraint.constant = 0
        myTextView.isAccessibilityElement = false
    }

    // Action for "BUTTON H 44"
    @IBAction func heightIsNotZero(_ sender: UIButton) {
        heightConstraint.constant = 44
        myTextView.isAccessibilityElement = true
    }
}
```

The final result with the VoiceOver gestures is displayed hereafter:
[image]

1. Double tap the `Button H 0` to disable the textview accessibility and set its height to 0.
2. Select the next element to check if the focus is still possible on the textview despite its zero height.
3. Double tap the `Button H 44` to enable the textview accessibility and set its height to 44.
4. Select the previous element to check if the textview can be focused.
5. The focus is made on the textview without turning VoiceOver on/off.

Following this rationale, you can notice that **VoiceOver is working properly on changing height constraint for a textview in iOS**.

Comment: Hi @XLE_22 , I'm doing the same thing on the button click. In my case the UITextField is inside a TableViewCell which on expansion increases the size of the cell too. Plus it works fine when I switch on/off the Voiceover.

Comment: @user_aj: you never mentioned a TableviewCell in your post. That's definitely another problem than the one you initially described. Accept this answer for people who are looking for a VoiceOver TextView solution and open another topic dedicated to your real problem dealing with a Textview in a TableviewCell: be as accurate as possible and add as many details as you can to get the proper solution, please. Time spent drafting solutions must be effective...